# Rails each do average

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Im trying to get the average of price in the products table and store it in a variable called average.

Heres my code:

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
    @average = 0
    @i = 0

    @products.each do |p|
       i += 1
       average += p.price
    end

    average = average / i
end
```

Im getting error "undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass" on the "i += 1 statement"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting up `i` as an *instance* variable (`@i`), but calling it as a regular variable (`i`).

Either take away the `@` when you initialize it to zero, or change references to `i` to `@i`.

You probably don't want to re-use your `i` after this method, so you probably just want a regular variable. Like so. (You also have a similar problem with your `@average`, which you probably *do* want to persist after the method.)

```
def index
    @products = Product.all
    @average = 0
    i = 0

    @products.each do |p|
       i += 1
       @average += p.price
    end

    @average = @average / i
end
```

There is a much cleaner way of working out averages from ActiveRecord collections (you could be doing it directly in the SQL), but I won't mention those since what you're doing is probably a good way to learn Ruby.

Comment: Thanks. I thought you had to declare all variables with the @ sign. Im a java programmer trying to learn ruby

Comment: Ah, makes sense. I'm sure you know the difference, but for the purpose of anyone else reading: `@` denotes an instance variable, that is, a variable that exists within the scope of the entire object. The other type of variable used (sans-`@`) is only available within the most "local" scope. As I say, though, this is a pretty inefficient way to work out averages, but it's a good start.

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby on Rails there are predefined [aggregate methods](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations/ClassMethods.html) for your models to calculate average, sum, count, minimum, maximum, etc.

In your special case, you can do the following:

```
@average = Product.average(:price)
```

It will dispatch the actual work to the SQL which will do a better job than a Ruby code. It will produce an SQL query like (this is a MySQL example):

```
SELECT AVG(`products`.`price`) AS avg_id FROM `products`
```

Answer (score 0):

Use.. i think you forgot @ sign

```
def index
        @products = Product.all
        @average = 0
        @i = 0

        @products.each do |p|
           @i += 1
           @average += p.price
        end

        @average = @average / @i
    end
```